# Failed to initiate service connection to simulator in xcode9-beta

Tags: ios11, xcode9-beta

My project is very basic one. Simply it shows hello world label to the user. When i run my simulator for the first time it is taking around 5-6 minutes to run and finally it was ended up with an error message as **"Failed to initiate service connection to simulator   request timed out"**. When i run again by pressing run button in Xcode9 there is no issue. I want to know what is the reason behind it and also i observed that my mac is getting slow while running my simulator, why?.

There is no issue when i run on any physical device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had a similar problem. For me the reason was there was an instance of the non-beta simulator running in the background. Make sure to quit all Xcode related applications and restart.